# Managing exit code after context initialization exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exit-code, spring-bean

I would like to know if there is any way to set the returned exit code after a *BeanCreationException* occured during the Spring initialization.

So far the only solution that I have found is to wrap the entire application inside a **try/catch**, and call System.exit after the block :

```java
    public static int runForExitCode (String[] args) {
        try {
            return SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return extractExitCodeFrom(e) ;
        }
    }
```

This solution works as expected, but it makes me work out of Spring container, and adds an entire layer of complexity to my application, making the tests much more difficult to write...
For this reason, I would like to use a Spring-provided tool to manage the exit code.

I know there are some beans that can be implemented to handle the exit code : `ExitCodeGenerator` and `ExitCodeExceptionMapper`, but I have not been able to make them work after an exception that comes during context initialization, such as BeanCreationException.

Because the initialization is the time during which beans are created, I understand that I need a special way to handle the exceptions. I would have expected to find some property to be declared in the `spring.factories` file, but the closest tool that I found was the `FailureAnalyzer` interface, which only allows one to describe the exception with words.

I know that one might avoid the problem by moving the dangerous code from the bean declaration into the `ApplicationRunner` method, but I cannot proceed this way : I am trying to handle the possible Database exceptions, that might occur during a Spring Batch application initialization.

I may be missing some Spring dedicated feature, or thinking the wrong way. Maybe the **try/catch** block is the only solution to be kept ?

Thank you for your time,

Arturito

Comment: We had the same problem and solved it by implementing a `FailureAnalyzer` that calls `System.exit(...)` on certain types of exceptions and thus made sure that e.g. on a `BeanCreationException` the process was terminated with a specific exit-code.

However, the solution is not really 'nice' and since we are currently updating Spring-Boot in that service, we are again looking for a 'better' solution (which hopefully requires less custom code).